# Alternate ways WCF Authentication with netTcpBinding binding

Tags: wcf, authentication, nettcpbinding

I'm writing a WCF server for an intranet application. I'm a newbie on WCF And have some queries on the Authentication. For this server the binding will netTcp, Its suggested to use netTcpBinding with Windows Authentication. But for my requirement I need a custom login where user will be validated with his own credentials not windows credentials.
   I'm Planning to have a service contract implemented this way and validate the Login credentials

```
*[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
public interface Iservice
{
    [OperationContract]
    String Login(String username, String password);
}   
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerSession) ]
public class serviceclass : Iservice
{
    String Login(String username, String password);
    {
        //Validate uname and password with DB.
        if (validate)
            return OperationContext.Current.SessionId;
        else return String.Empty;   
    }
}*
Is this a good approach or is there a better approach to acheive this.
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to you to use the [UserNamePasswordValidator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for custom validation, it fits to your requirement.

You just need to inherit and implement validate from UserNamePasswordValidator class like this:

```
public class CustomUserNameValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
  public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
  {
    if (null == userName || null == password)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }

    if (!(userName == "test1" && password == "1tset") && !(userName == "test2" && password == "2tset"))
    {
        // This throws an informative fault to the client.
        throw new FaultException("Unknown Username or Incorrect Password");
        // When you do not want to throw an infomative fault to the client,
        // throw the following exception.
        // throw new SecurityTokenException("Unknown Username or Incorrect Password");
    }
   }
}
```

You can replace static username and password and validate it in your data storage.

Service configuration :

```
<serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior name="CustomValidator">
    <serviceCredentials>
      <userNameAuthentication
        userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
        customUserNamePasswordValidatorType=
           "MyAssembly.CustomUserNameValidator, MyAssembly"/>      
    </serviceCredentials>
  </behavior>
<serviceBehaviors>

<netTcpBinding>
  <binding name="tcpWithMessageSecurity">
    <security mode="Message" >
      <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
    </security>
  </binding>
</netTcpBinding>
```

For client side you can use Credentials to populate username and password.

```
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "user";
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Passsord = "password";
```